# To find the file contents by matching strings and output those which are not found in PowerShell 2.0

Tags: powershell-2.0

I have the code snippet which checks the contents with the strings in file and lists the strings which do not appear in the file.The below code snippet works fine in PowerShell 5.0, but in PowerShell 2.0 I get error as:

> Foreach object: Cannot convert 'System.object[]'  to type 'System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock' required by a parameter 'Process'.Specified method is not supported in power shell 2.0

The below code is both for PowerShell 2.0 and 5.0. But currently it works on 5.0 only.

```
$Pattern = 'Hello|new|World|Hi|greet'

$Test = (Get-Content -Path .\file.txt | Select-String -Pattern $Pattern -AllMatches) | foreach {$_.matches.Value} $($pattern -split '\|') | where {$Test -notcontains $_}
```

With the file.txt having following contents:

```
$q = Get-Content -Path .\file.txt |Select-String 'Hello' -SimpleMatch    
$w = Get-Content -Path .\file.txt |Select-String 'new' -SimpleMatch
$e = Get-Content -Path .\file.txt |Select-String 'World' -SimpleMatch
$r = Get-Content -Path .\file.txt |Select-String 'Hi' -SimpleMatch
$t = Get-Content -Path .\file.txt |Select-String 'greet' -SimpleMatch
```

I have tried the new code as:

```
$strings = ('Hello','new','World','Hi','greet')
$file    = '.\file.txt'

$Found = (Get-Content -Path $file |
         Select-String -Pattern $strings -AllMatches).Matches.Value 
$Missing = $Strings | Where {$Found -notcontains $_}

if ($Missing) {
    "Strings missing in $file"
    $Missing
} else {
    "All strings present in $file"
}
```

I am able to get output as list of all strings instead of getting list of missing strings. How can the problem be solved?

Comment: `foreach {$_.matches.Value} $($pattern -split '\|')` is not valid syntax. What is that supposed to accomplish?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers The code snippet searches for the string in the file and output the strings which are not found . The text file would contain like                                  
 $q = Get-Content -Path .\file.txt |Select-String 'Hello' -SimpleMatch

$w = Get-Content -Path .\file.txt |Select-String 'new' -SimpleMatch

$e = Get-Content -Path .\file.txt |Select-String 'World' -SimpleMatch

$r = Get-Content -Path .\file.txt |Select-String 'Hi' -SimpleMatch

$t = Get-Content -Path .\file.txt |Select-String 'greet' -SimpleMatch

Comment: Please update your question with sample input and the output you expect from that input. Do not post it in a comment as that is unreadable. [Edit] your question instead.

Comment: Again, what *are* the "desired results"?

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers, there was an error executing the code snippet. The error has been showed in the above post. Do we have any solution for that?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, I have tried the new code which has been shared in my question. How can the problem be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last code snippet from your updated question is trying to use a feature called [member enumeration](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2012/06/14/new-v3-language-features.aspx). That feature was introduced with PowerShell v3 and is not available in PowerShell v2.

Change the statement

```
$Found = (Get-Content -Path $file |
         Select-String -Pattern $strings -AllMatches).Matches.Value
```

into

```
$Found = Get-Content -Path $file |
         Select-String -Pattern $strings -AllMatches |
         Select-Object -Expand Matches |
         Select-Object -Expand Value
```

and the problem will disappear.